# Do you know an eloquent presentation of the differences between the miscellaneous locative prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, disambiguation

To my mind, some locative prepositions make distinctions that are rather subtle, and I'm not sure I understand them well. So I'm looking for concrete examples where an explanation of the difference in meaning is given. Just like the famous "*salti sur la tablo/salti sur la tablon*" for the accusative.

The locative propositions I'm aware of are:

- *antaŭ*
- *apud*
- *ĉe*
- *ĉirkaŭ*
- *cis*
- *de*
- *en*
- *post*
- *sub*
- *super*
- *sur*
- *tra*
- *trans*

Moreover, all of these propositions can be prefixed with *mal-*.

Also, only usable when there is an idea of movement are *sob* and *sor*, which are suggested as replacement of *malsupren* and *supren*.

With the idea of movement also come *al*, *(ek)de*, *el*, and *ĝis*.

So do you have clarifying examples?

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you're asking - but I'm pretty sure you're overthinking it -- as witnessed by the inclusion of the unofficial word "cis". PMEG, by the way, explains "cis" as "maltrans" - which would make "malcis" a strange word indeed. My suggestion is for this question to be clarified or closed.

Comment: I disagree with you regarding *mal-*. The only prepositions I've seen prefixed with *mal-* are *antaux* and *supren*. *Mal-* doesn't just negate, it creates opposites, and with some of these prepositions that wouldn't make much sense to me. But I might be missing something. Can you explain to me what the opposites of "cxe", "apud", "cxirkaux" and "tra" are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonvolu ekzameni [la paĝon](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/lokaj_prepozicioj) ĉe Lernu.net. Uzado de *mal-* estas malofta krom kun *antaŭ*.

#### antaŭ — post

- La aktoro staras antaŭ la kurteno kaj parolas al la spektantaro.
- La aktorino staras post [= malantaŭ] la kurteno kaj aŭskultas.

#### ĉe — apud

La diferenco koncernas fizikan proksimecon:

- Mi ne loĝas ĉe mia frato, sed mia loĝejo estas apud la lia.
- Li havis glavon ĉe la femuro kaj lancon terpikitan apud li.

#### sur — super

La diferenco koncernas tuŝecon:

- La telero kuŝas sur la tablo; la lampo pendas super la tablo.

*Sureco* ne ĉiam egalas plialtecon:

- Li rigardis supren al la fresko sur la plafono.

#### sub = malsuper

Eble iu skribus:

- La tria etaĝo estas sub la kvara; la dua etaĝo estas malsuper la kvara.

sed ĝenerale oni ne faras distingon.

#### cis — trans (ĉi-flanke — aliflanke)

- Mia domo staras cis la rivero; lia domo staras trans la rivero.

#### tra — trans

- Mi marŝis tra la koridoro salutante plurajn homojn.
- Mia pordo estis trans la koridoro; por atingi ĝin, mi devis marŝi nur trans la koridoron.

Comment: Bone. sub = malsuper, kaj ĉu malsur havas malpi longa sinonimo?

Comment: *malsur* estas sensencajxo. Io povas estis sur la planko. Io povas esti sur la plafono.

Comment: @psychoslave I don't think Andrew is saying that *sub=malsuper*, but rahter that the two can be used as *sur* and *super*. *Sur* means on, while *super* means above. As in the example with the floors, *sub* would then mean "directly underneath", while *malsuper* would mean "below".

Answer (score 1):

This site is pretty good: http://esperanto.50webs.com/EsrGrammar-3_10.html

This chapter talks about prepositions: http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq050.html